# CSS :not on the parent does not work for descendant selectors but it does for child selectors, unless you explicitly specify the parent element type

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnrn97a7/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="c1">
        c1 should be black
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
        c2 should be black
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
        c3 should be black
    </div>
</div>
<div id="somethingelse">
    <div class="c1">
       c1 should be red
    </div>
    <div class="c2">
        c2 should be red
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
        c3 should be red
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
:not(#outer) .c1 {
    color: #ff0000;
}

div:not(#outer) .c2 {
    color: #ff0000;
}

:not(#outer) > .c3 {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

With c1, I have a descendant rule that does not include the parent element type. With c2, I have a descendant rule that does include the parent element type. With c3, I have an immediate child rule that does not include the parent element type. Only c2 and c3 work as intended. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:not(#outer) .c1` means: select all elements with class `c1` and which are descendants of an element which doesn't have the ID `outer`.

This matches your first element, because it has class `c1`, and is a descendant of `body`, which doesn't have the ID `outer`.

Instead, `div:not(#outer) .c1` means: select all elements with class `c1` and which are descendants of a `div` element which doesn't have the ID `outer`. This doesn't match the second element, because all its ancestors either aren't `div` elements or have the ID `outer`.

Fianlly, `:not(#outer) > .c1` means: select all elements with class `c1` and which are a child of an element which doesn't have the ID `outer`. This doesn't match the third element, because its parent has the ID `outer`.